# Get full text content of html email in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

How do i get the full text content of an html email as single line string in rspec?

Let's say this is the mail.html.haml:

```
%p 
  This product is worth: 
  = @amount
  So buy it now!
```

In rspec i send the email first and then do this:

```
expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.html_part.body).to include("This product is worth: €30 So buy it now")
```

or:

```
expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.html_part.body.raw_source).to include("This product is worth: €30 So buy it now")
```

or:

```
expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.html_part.body.raw_source).to have_content("This product is worth: €30 So buy it now")
```

These doesnt work because the html outputs to rspec like this:

```
 + This product is worth:
 + €30
 + So buy it now!
```

So my original code is right but i cant seem to grab it in rspec. How do i combine these 3 lines to 1 single line so i can call include or have_content on it correctly?

***EDIT**

```
Failure/Error:
       expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.html_part.body.raw_source).to have_content(%q|This product is worth:
                                                                                               €30
                                                                                               So buy it now!|)

       expected        
       <p>
       This product is worth:
       €30
       So buy it now!
       Good luck!
       </p>
```

Comment: change `"This product is worth: €30 So buy it now"` to `"This product is worth:\n€30\nSo buy it now"` ?

Comment: Thanks for helping but actually i am looking for a way to do it without putting extra escaping inside of my strings because it becomes hard to read/maintain if you have larger amounts of texts which also happen to change sometimes.

Comment: added one alternative as answer. check if that is helpful

Comment: BTW: using "This product is worth:\n€30\nSo buy it now" doesn't work either in this case.

Comment: because it is also expecting enclosing <p></p> tag which is not in your expectation?

Comment: No because have_content only looks at the text and not html tags, tried it aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple. The HAML needs to be inline like this:

```
%p This product is worth: #{@amount} So buy it now!
```

or the variable needs to be interpolated like this:

```
%p 
  This product is worth: 
  #{@amount}
  So buy it now!
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.html_part.body.raw_source).to have_content(
%q|This product is worth:
€30
So buy it now|)
```

I wouldn't suggest modifying the retrieval since that will technically make the spec irrelevant as match is not exactly same as what is being rendered. You can break it down like above which will save from escaping the content.

If you have lot of such tests, you may want to persist the expected result in some datastore (db/factory/yaml etc) and compare against them.

Comment: This does seem to split the text the same way RSpec outputs the email in the terminal but the test still fails, so i guess it doesn't read it that way.

Comment: Can you post what it expects and what it gets - the result you get in your spec failure

Comment: added the failure to OP